# Are tfbnw.net email addresses suspicious for facebook login

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a mobile app that allows logging in with facebook, when a user logs in I pull their email from the graph api but I just got a couple of logins with email addresses with @tfbnw.net domains which I guess is for test users while developing on facebook.  I didnt generate these so is this someone doing something shady to login to my app or just expected behavior for some users given their settings?

Mobile app coded in react-native, using expo

Answer (score 9):

Those seem to be the internal facebook QA team going through your APPs and manually checking if you're following all facebook's guidelines.

Facebook auditing your app basically.... or at least they did to mine because right after those @tfbnw.net email registrations came in, I checked my facebook app settings and sure enough, I got an alert and an email shortly after. But never received those @tfbnw.net emails before today on any other facebook logins.

Answer (score 7):

I have checked my account and it looks like a generic test user `Open Graph Test User` gets created automatically, according to which product you enable in your app. It gets created for example, if you enable facebook login or messenger platform.
not something shady IMHO[image]

Comment: Yeah in my case it wasnt that something was being created on the facebook side.  It is that someone actually logged into my mobile app using facebook authentication and when I query their email address I get a tfbnw.net address.

Comment: @StevenShadman was this happening when the fb app (not yours) was in testing mode? I should have thousands of tfbnw's if not