# What are these Facebook bot-like users with tfbnw.net domains?

Tags: web-applications, bots, facebook-login

Suddenly I started getting one of these users per day signing into my web app.
Here is an example email: xfwpqahlcl_1576843160@tfbnw.net

They only sign in with Facebook and do some minor activity.
Not harmful, but quite annoying to be honest, they screw up my metrics.

Are they legit somehow? Is there any way to stop them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I exclude any malicious activity
https://www.whois.com/whois/tfbnw.net

Those seem to be a genuine internal Facebook QA team test.

Comment: I just found another similar answer here on stackoverflow :)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54261262/are-tfbnw-net-email-addresses-suspicious-for-facebook-login/54736959

Comment: The FaceBook Network :D

Comment: Can confirm. I'm currently dealing with a member of FB QA, who is showing me screenshots of what he's doing in my app.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar episode today where two of suspicious user accounts have been created with apparently randomly generated data on iwillfindyou.love using emails from domain tfbnw.net.

Due to the fact that I have not been informed about this Facebook activity beforehand, I had to suspend these users as they violate my website rules.

It may well be a malicious activity third party is conducting **through** the Facebook platform, so I would be very careful here.

To answer question whether this is legit, I would say **no**.

[image: (Fake) users created by or via Facebook platform.]

Comment: It is a genuine internal Facebook QA team test :) ..nothing dodgy or malicious

Answer (score 0):

Those are test users created by facebook you can create them yourself on the app settings, no need to worry.